# Select top N from my_table in druid.io - a simplest request - how?

Tags: druid, nosql

How can I request a few "records" from [Druid](http://druid.io)  without using any search/filter criteria using as simple as possible request? I relational db I'd do that by select top 10 from my_table.

The reason I want to do that is to make sure data exists and see its structure.

Answer (score 0):

Druid has a simple [SELECT query](http://druid.io/docs/latest/development/select-query.html). Just use something like this:

```
 {
   "queryType": "select",
   "dataSource": "wikipedia",
   "intervals": [
     "2015-01-01/2016-01-02"
   ],
   "pagingSpec":{"pagingIdentifiers": {}, "threshold":10}
 }
```